# Exclude Media Library From Lucene Search /Indexing

Tags: media-library, lucene

How do i  Exclude Media Library From  Lucene Search /Indexing in 8.2 ??

Comment: Do you have a root which points to the Media Library item in your index file?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is this a custom index? If so, how have you configured it?

Comment: No its not customized i get the following error and CMS hangs when i click the media library .https://www.screencast.com/t/Ezak1BFLa

Comment: @jai please add more information to your post use the `Edit` link. Also add what you have tried and anything else relevant. As it stands, this is a low quality post and is unlikely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would not `exclude` the media library and focus on `including` only the folders you want. I would also make sure that you are not doing this to the master index as the Sitecore content editor uses the for its core functionality.

You can use the locations section of your search config file to define explicitly which folder you want to include.

```
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
    <crawlerClientA type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/ClientA/Home/</Root>
    </crawlerClientA>
    <crawlerClientB type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content/Clientb/Home/</Root>
    </crawlerClientB>
</locations>
```